# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver error in Ubuntu terminal

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc-odbc

I have the following code from tutorialpoints but can't make it work.

```
import java.sql.*;

public class JDBCExample1 {
   // JDBC driver name and database URL
   static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
   static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test";

   //  Database credentials
   static final String USER = "root";
   static final String PASS = "abhishek";

   public static void main(String[] args) {
   Connection conn = null;
   try{
      //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      //STEP 3: Open a connection
      System.out.println("Connecting to a selected database...");
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
      System.out.println("Connected database successfully...");
   }catch(SQLException se){
      //Handle errors for JDBC
      se.printStackTrace();
   }catch(Exception e){
      //Handle errors for Class.forName
      e.printStackTrace();
   }finally{
      //finally block used to close resources
      try{
         if(conn!=null)
            conn.close();
      }catch(SQLException se){
         se.printStackTrace();
      }//end finally try
   }//end try
   System.out.println("Goodbye!");
}//end main
}//end JDBCExample
```

I have added the jar to path and used other techniques like `java -cp .:mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar JDBCExample1` but I can't make it work in terminal. I don't want to use IDE. I have seen al posts on stackoverflow but none helped. Please solve this.

Comment: Adding a jar file to the `PATH` does not work. It should be added to the *classpath*, either by setting the `CLASSPATH` environment variable or by using the `-cp` or `-classpath` options. If it doesn't work, then you've made a mistake somewhere, for example a typo, a space in a place where there shouldn't be one etc.

Comment: The command you're mentionning (java -cp ...) *is* the solution. What do you mean you can't get it to work ?

Comment: Is `mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar` in the current directory when you run that command? If not, then use the correct path to the jar file, for example: `java -cp .:/home/abishek/libs/mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar JDBCExample1`

Comment: I have the jar in the same folder but that doesn't help. By what command should I add the jar to the CLASSPATH. I used export in bash but that didn't help. :(